# Swift segue fatal error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

In **ViewController**:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Segue") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2;

        svc.vericik = self.vericik   
    }
}


@IBAction func gotoView2(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue", sender: self)
    self.presentViewController(ViewController2(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In **ViewController2**:

```
var vericik: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var VeriYeri: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        VeriYeri.text = vericik
    }
```

When, I click button on ViewController, ViewController2 page comes to screen and I can see segue data which come from ViewController. But after that, an **error** occurs:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: check that vericik is not nil.

Comment: Also, do you need "presentViewController"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
self.presentViewController(ViewController2(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This line of code is creating a **second** `ViewController2`.  The first one was created for you when you did `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue", sender: self)`.  This second `ViewController2` never gets initialized, so its `vericik` property is still `nil` when `viewDidLoad` runs and implicitly unwraps the optional with `VeriYeri.text = vericik` (because `vericik` is declared as `String!`).

To fix the problem, simply delete this line of code:

```
self.presentViewController(ViewController2(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It is not needed.  The segue creates `ViewController2` for you, and you initialize it in `prepareForSegue`, and then the segue presents `ViewController2`.  There's absolutely no need for you to call `presentViewController` when using segues.

Comment: Just wanted your opinion, should he/she also check that the text value is not nil or is not needed?

Comment: @the_pantless_coder, in this case they should not check for `nil` and just let it crash.  A `nil` value would be a bug by the programmer, and it is quicker to find a bug in your program if it crashes than when it simply does nothing quietly.  This is the same reason you don't check for `nil` when accessing @IBOutlets, because a crash will tell you that you forgot to wire them up. The times you should check for `nil` is when the value comes from the user or from the network, because you don't want to crash in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, you are setting your `vericik` variable to `nil`. Can you print that value before you try setting it before the segue? If it's `nil`, don't set it as the text, because that's causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that your string is not nil. Try this.

ViewController2

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           if vericik != nil {
            //String is not nil, set textfield/label whatever
            VeriYeri.text = vericik
            }
    }
```

ViewController

```
if (segue.identifier == "Segue") {
    var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2;
         if self.vericik != nil {
              //String is not nil. All is good :)
              svc.vericik = self.vericik
          } else {
             //String is nil, do something...maybe set default text
             svc.vericik = "some text"
          }
}
```